# org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException during delete

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using 
Spring = 3.2.3.RELEASE
And Hibernate-annotations = 3.5.6-Final

I have bean :

```
@Entity
public class Step implements Serializable, Comparable<Step> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5345848109844492261L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Column
private String description;

@Column(nullable = false)
private boolean active;

@Column(nullable = false)
private int stepOrder;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String command;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "elementID")
private Element element;

@Column
private String arg1;

@Column
private String arg2;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "testCaseID", nullable = false)
private TestCase testCase;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "releaseID", nullable = false)
private ReleaseEntity releaseEntity;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "updatedBy", nullable = false)
private User updatedBy;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(columnDefinition = "timestamp", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
private Date updatedDate;

@Column(nullable = false)
private boolean deleted;

.....
getters/ setters , equals / hashCode
```

And I have dao for persists this entity :

```
@Repository("StepDAO")
@Transactional
public class StepDAOMysql extends BaseDAOMysql implements StepDAO
{
@Override
public void delete(Step step)
{
if (hasHistory(step))
{
    List<?> listToDelete = hibernateTemplate.find(
        "from StepHistory st where st.step=?", step);
    hibernateTemplate.deleteAll(listToDelete);
}
hibernateTemplate.evict(step);
hibernateTemplate.delete(step);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public boolean hasHistory(Step step)
{
return !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(hibernateTemplate.find(
    "from StepHistory st where st.step=?", step));
}
```

When I try to execute delete of my DAO I get

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: a different object with the same    identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.livenation.automation.bean.Step#1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.livenation.automation.bean.Step#1]
```

Actually I confused . Googled a lot about duplicate exception and all post is about duplicate exception during saveOrUpdate but nobody face with it on delete . But anyway I insert suggested solution - evict method and didn't help .
Probably it is some bug in mapping exceptions between hibernate and spring ? (I saw such problems before in other projects )

**EDIT :** it appears that problem related only to execution of this method in test context and if execute it in production no exception happens 
the test code is very simple

```
@Test
public void canDeleteStepWithHistory()
{
linkedStep.setArg1(getRandomString());   
dao.saveOrUpdate(linkedStep); // in line above we change value of linkedStep , DAO will detect this and will create appropriate StepHistory object that linked with linkedStep . This is main goal ofg test check that DAO can delete such object 
dao.delete(linkedStep);
Step fromDB = dao.getById(linkedStep.getId());
Assertions.assertThat(fromDB).isNull();
}
```

Tests executes using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/test-dispatcher.xml")

Comment: can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: sure , http://pastebin.com/itH3DnKA .

Comment: this is weird, aren't you executing this code 2 times in the same session?

Comment: as far as I know SpringJUnit4ClassRunner not execute tests twice and the test above fails even if I execute it alone